# Cannot set OpenCL kernel argument with buffer memory object

Tags: rust, opencl

I have the following simple OpenCL kernel, that simply copies all entries pointed at a to b

```
__kernel void mmcopy(__global float* a, __global float* b) {
    unsigned pos = get_global_id(0);
    b[pos] = a[pos];
}
```

The following code snippet shows the opencl function calls for creating a buffer memory object out of four floats, and setting the first argument on the kernel with the buffer object.

```
let mut v = [1f32, 1f32, 1f32, 1f32];

let size = mem::size_of_val(&v) as size_t;
let mut error_buffer = 0 as i32;
let buffer = unsafe {
    clCreateBuffer(
        context.id.unwrap(),
        (CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE) as u64,
        size,
        v.as_mut_ptr() as *mut c_void,
        &mut error_buffer,
    )
};

let real_size = mem::size_of::<cl_mem>() as size_t;

let error = unsafe {
    clSetKernelArg(
        self.id.unwrap(), // here `self` is a wrapper. `id` is of type `cl_kernel`
        0 as cl_uint,
        real_size,
        buffer as *const c_void,
    )
};
```

However, executing the code results in an error `CL_INVALID_MEM_OBJECT`. 
it looks like creating the buffer didn't succeed, but returned without an error.

The [spec](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL//sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) is also not very precise when it comes to describe the error in more detail:

> for an argument declared to be a memory object when the specified arg_value is not a valid memory object.

**note**: the OpenCL functions, and types have been generated by rust-bindgen.

### update 1

To clarify how the opaque types are represented in rust, here is the representation of cl_mem,

```
pub struct _cl_mem {
    _unused: [u8; 0],
}
pub type cl_mem = *mut _cl_mem;
```

the ffi to clSetKernelArg

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn clSetKernelArg(
        kernel: cl_kernel, 
        arg_index: cl_uint,
        arg_size: size_t,
        arg_value: *const ::std::os::raw::c_void,
    ) -> cl_int;
}
```

and clCreateBuffer

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn clCreateBuffer(
        context: cl_context,
        flags: cl_mem_flags,
        size: size_t,
        host_ptr: *mut ::std::os::raw::c_void,
        errcode_ret: *mut cl_int,
    ) -> cl_mem;
}
```

In my understanding rust(-bindgen) uses zero sized types (ZST) to represent [external opaque types](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1861-extern-types.md). So basically cl_mem is already a pointer.

### update 2

According to [pmdj](https://stackoverflow.com/users/48660/pmdj)'s answer the correct way is to pass a **pointer** to the cl_mem buffer

```
let error = unsafe {
    clSetKernelArg(
        self.id.unwrap(), // here `self` is a wrapper. `id` is of type `cl_kernel`
        0 as cl_uint,
        real_size,
        &buffer as *const _ as *const c_void,
    )
};
```

That actually fixes the problem, and set the return value to `CL_SUCCESS`. The spec for [clSetKernelArg](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL//sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/clSetKernelArg.html) also mentions a **pointer** to data

> A pointer to data that should be used as the argument value for argument specified by arg_index. The argument data pointed to by arg_value is copied and the arg_value pointer can therefore be reused by the application after clSetKernelArg returns. The argument value specified is the value used by all API calls that enqueue kernel (clEnqueueNDRangeKernel) until the argument value is changed by a call to clSetKernelArg for kernel [...]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before I dig in, I'll point out that I'm a relative beginner with Rust and I'm not particularly familiar with what bindgen produces, but I know OpenCL quite well. So please bear with me if my Rust syntax is off.

The most obvious thing that sticks out for me is that passing the buffer to `clSetKernelArg` using `buffer as *const c_void` looks suspicious. My understanding is that your code is roughly equivalent to this C:

```
cl_int error_buffer = 0;
cl_mem buffer = clCreateBuffer(
        context.id,
        (CL_MEM_COPY_HOST_PTR | CL_MEM_READ_WRITE),
        size,
        v,
        &error_buffer
    );

size_t real_size = siezof(buffer);
cl_int error = clSetKernelArg(self.id, 0, real_size, buffer);
```

However, the last line is incorrect, it should be:

```
cl_int error = clSetKernelArg(self.id, 0, real_size, &buffer);
// yes, we want a POINTER to the buffer handle-------^
```

Although `cl_mem` is defined as a pointer to an opaque struct type, you need to pass the *pointer to that pointer* as the argument, just as with any other type of kernel argument: conceptually, I find it useful to think of it as `clSetKernelArg` performing a `memcpy(internal_buffer, arg_value, arg_size);` internally - so `arg_size` must always be the size of the object pointed to by `arg_value`. I find this helps me work out the correct level of indirection.

So in Rust this is probably along the lines of:

```
let error = unsafe {
    clSetKernelArg(
        self.id.unwrap(),
        0 as cl_uint,
        real_size,
        &buffer as *const c_void,
    )
};
```

but I haven't run it past `rustc` so it's probably wrong. You get the drift though.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To get the pointer to buffer would be `&buffer as *const _ as *const c_void`. this actually removes the runtime error, but subsequent calls to `clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(...)` and then do a blocking read on the buffer returns a zero filled array.

Comment: Ok. I Got it! The mistake was getting a pointer to an array for global_work_size via `get_ptr()`, which is wrong but casting around does the trick. You have definitely earned your bounty! Such a pity, that it all boiled down to wrong type casting and referencing. I will also update my answer to clarify it even more.